# Where are all the places in the torah with extra dots over the words?

Tags: parashat-nitzavim, torah-writing

This morning during the reading from Nitzavim I saw the extra dots over a couple words in D'varim 29:28 and tried to remember what that meant.  I found Rashi's commentary on [t deut 29:28 lr], which says in part:

> There is a dot placed over [each letter of] the words לָנוּ וּלְבָנֵינוּ here, to teach us homiletically that even for open sins [which were not brought to judgment, God] did not punish the whole community-until Israel crossed the Jordan. For then, they accepted upon themselves the oath at Mount Gerizim and Mount Ebal, and thereby [formally] became responsible for one another (Sanh. 43b). [**When dots are placed over letters of the Torah, this denotes an exclusion of some sort.** In our context, our Rabbis teach us that the exclusion refers to the period prior to the crossing of the Jordan.]

My question is about that (unsourced) editorial note at the end saying that dots over letters denote an exclusion of some sort.  I wanted to look at the other places where these dots appear to see what's being excluded in those cases.  I looked up Sanhedrin 43b, which talks about this passage but doesn't generalize.

Where are all the places that the torah uses these dots?

Comment: You should know dotting letters like that is a common old scribal technique for striking out mistakes. >700 years ago this would have been obvious to anyone who could read.

Comment: Hi Monica. Avot Derabbi Natan, ch. 34 Mishnah 5 lists the 10 places in the Torah that have dotted letters / words. One advantage of reading this source is that it gives a reason, as well as the location. I assume that your Hebrew is good. (It shouldn't be to hard to understand this one, anyway, as the main purpose is to cite the location.) Here is a link to an online Hebrew version: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/avot/34-2.htm. Shanah Tovah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Fascinating. Any source for this or similar ideas? Shanah Tovah.